# SQL query case and group by statement clarification

Tags: mysql

i have confused with this below query..

```
select 
    kgfs,
    branch,
    (case when (Overdue_Days_as_on_30Sep2016) between 1 and 30 
        then sum(Total_Cash_Collected_for_the_period)/sum(principaloverdue_as_on_30SEP2016+InterestOverdue_as_on_30SEP2016) 
        else 0 end
    ) as 1to30perc
from 
bietl_archive.quick_cbs_loan_dump_01Oct2016to13Oct2016
group by kgfs,branch
```

When i"m using this query result will be automatically going to else part..what mistake i did..please can you people explain me

Comment: thanks krish giving a clear view